# File Descriptors: is it possible to non-block `write` arbitrary lengths of data?

Tags: asynchronous, file-descriptor

Is it be possible to read and write arbitrary sizes of data using a file-descriptor as a handle (perhaps with a custom kernel driver)?

Or is there an OS-mandated limit to the buffer size used for transferring data through file descriptors?

I know that

- **files** block due to slow disk access time
- **sockets** (stream and dgram) have maximum packet sizes
- **pipes** and **fifos** also seem to have some sort of buffer limitation

I would like to create an fd that will never block on writes.

### Example

**Usage** would be something like this:

```
fd = open("/dev/new_buffer")
write(fd, data, huge_size, NON_BLOCK)
read(fd, data2, huge_size, NON_BLOCK)
```

**Backend** implementation would be something like this
(excuse the over simplification):

```
on_write(fd, data, size, opts)
{
  void* buffers[fd] = malloc(size);
  memcpy(buffers[fd], data, size);
}

on_read(fd, data, size, opts)
{
  memcpy(data, buffers[fd], size);
}
```